# Using MySQL Distinct to display the unique values in the column which has some values with special characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a column with values like this.

1. Thun
2. Uebeschi
3. Uetendorf
4. Thun
5. Oberei bei Süderen
6. Süderen

I running this query to get the distinct values of that column.

```
Select Distinct coloumn_name from table_name.
```

I am getting the results like this

1. Thun
2. Uebeschi
3. Uetendorf

Since the values `Oberei bei Süderen`,`Süderen` contains special character `ü`
, It is not getting retrieved.But i need to get those values also. Is there any way to solve this.
Column properties are below.
`TYPE:VARCHAR(100)`
`COLLATION:utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 1):

Try group by

```
 Select coloumn_name from table_name group by coloumn_name
```

Comment: @ Yatin Mistry I have tried that too, It is also giving the same results.

Comment: @Matchendran it's working i have just tried with COLLATION : utf8_general_ci

Comment: Still mysterious.I too tried that query but its not displaying.My collation is same as utf8_general_ci

Comment: Export your table structure and let me know the character set.

Comment: Character-Set is utf-8

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` (
  `phone` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; this my structure and collation is the same like you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61418/discussion-between-yatin-mistry-and-matchendran).